# How to load the profile of a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC Controller action for creating a new user. I'm trying to store the new users additional details, such as `FullName`.

Problem is the `Profile` is for the currently authenticated user, in my case the admin. How can I reference the profile of the newly created user?

```
var user = Membership.CreateUser(newUser.Username, newUser.Password, newUser.Email);
Profile.SetPropertyValue("fullname", newUser.FullName); //wrong - stored against the admin that is creating the user
user.??? //I do have the user, but can I get the profile?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a user will add it to the list of users. However, this does not authenticate or authorize the new user for the current request. You also need to authenticate the user in the current request context. Profile is not accessible immediately upon user creation.

If you want to create a Profile for a newly-created User in the same request, you need to call `HttpContext.Current.Profile.Initialize(userName, true)`.  ***[HttpContext.Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.profile.aspx)*** will give you the `ProfileBase`  object and then calling ***[Initialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151831.aspx)*** method will initialize the profile of the `userName` you pass to it.You can then populate the newly initialized profile and continue with your changes and save it.

Use `HttpContext.Current.Profile`, when it is required to create/access the Profile immediately upon creation. On other requests, you can use/continue with ***[ProfileBase.Create(userName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151825.aspx)*** to get an instance of a profile for the specified user name.

However, if you authenticate the user immediately upon creation, you will be able to access the profile in its simplest way.

Comment: Let me just get this straight, once I call `Profile.Initialize` I can then use `Profile.SetPropertyValue`?

Comment: Your last point, that's just `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to authenticate?

Comment: 1.) YES.  2.) SetAuthCookie()  will set the authentication ticket in the response , so the next request will be authenticated, but it does not affect the state of the current request.The easiest way to authenticate the user would be to call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage if you are using FormsAutthentication. This will cause a new HTTP request, which will authenticate the user.